# Call Method Every time Duplicate Object Added to HashSet

Tags: c#, class, hashset

I am Creating a list of Points using HashSet because I don't want duplicate Points in my list. Points have Three Properties X coordinate(double), Y Coordinate(double) and Tags(HashSet).Now what I want is whenever I add a duplicate point into HashSet it will also Add Tags of Duplicate Point to Matched Point.

#### Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleAppTest
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                var points = new Point2DHashSet()
                 {
                new Point2D(0,0,"Start"),
                new Point2D(10,0,"Int1"),
                new Point2D(10,10,"Int2"),
                new Point2D(0,10,"Int3"),
                new Point2D(0,0,"End")
                };

                Console.WriteLine(points.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Point2DHashSet : HashSet<Point2D>
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            foreach (var pt in this)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(pt.ToString());
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }

    public class Point2D : IEquatable<Point2D>
    {
        public double X { get; set; }
        public double Y { get; set; }
        public HashSet<string> Tags { get; set; }

        public Point2D()
        {
            Tags = new HashSet<string>();
        }

        public Point2D(double x, double y, string tag) : this()
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
            Tags.Add(tag);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{X:0.####},{Y:0.####},{string.Join(",", Tags)}";
        }

        public bool Equals(Point2D point)
        {
            return this.X == point.X && this.Y == point.Y;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is null) return false;
            return obj is Point2D point3D && Equals(point3D);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return X.GetHashCode() + Y.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Current Output

```
0,0,Start
10,0,Int1
10,10,Int2
0,10,Int3
```

#### Output I want

```
0,0,Start,End
10,0,Int1
10,10,Int2
0,10,Int3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Point2DHashSet needs an Add that does this custom logic of "if the object already exists add the incoming point's tag to the existing points tags hashset. You can't replace the base Add in your derived set, because the base is not virtual, but you can hide it:

```
public new bool Add(Point2D incoming){

  if(base.TryGetValue(incoming, out var existing))
    existing.Tags.UnionWith(incoming.Tags);
  else
    base.Add(incoming);
}
```

I think that's what you'll need..

Should be noted though that you won't get repeated tags, and tags won't necessarily appear in the same order they were added. Your output could easily be `0,0,End,Start`

Comment: TryGetValue value not available for .Net Standard 2 Any Alternative  available?

Comment: Ugh, honestly I think I'd throw HashSet away in this case and use a `Dictionary<string, object>` where key is Point2D and value object is always null, or come up a level and have a `Dictionary<Point2D, HashSet<string>>` and having the Point2D just have a single string not a HashSet

Comment: The Goal hear is Crete Multiple geometry seperatly and Combine at end ovelapping their Tags

Comment: Is is important to maintain order?

Comment: Order is not important but for printing, i should be able to sort it by x or y coordinate

Comment: I also don't want my Collection to Throw error if Duplicate is added @Caius , Tag is Property of Point not Collection , i want to Get list of  Point based on HashTag

Comment: If you don't want a Dictionary to throw you need to have a logic like `if(dict.ContainsKey(incoming)) dict[incoming].UnionWith(incoming.Tags); else dict[incoming].Tags = incoming.Tags;` - this is if you're using the  `Dictionary<Point2D, HashSet<String>>` way

Answer (score 0):

Current Solution

```
        public new bool Add(Point2D point)
        {
            var sucess = base.Add(point);
            if (!sucess)
            {
                UpdateTags(point);
            }
            return sucess;
        }

        private void UpdateTags(Point2D point)
        {
            TryGetValue(point, out Point2D pt);
            pt.Tags.UnionWith(point.Tags);
        }
```